# How do I block direct access to .aspx pages using IIS7's URLRewrite module?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using IIS7's URLRewrite feature to hide the `.aspx` extension in my ASP.NET WebForms application's URLs.

I'm using the following configuration:

```
<rule name="WebFormsToMVC" stopProcessing="true">  
  <match url="^(.*?)\.aspx\?*?.*$" />  
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />  
    </conditions>  
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />  
</rule>`
```

I can now browse to:

`http://www.mytest.com/contact`

and this is rewritten to:

`http://www.mytest.com/contact.aspx`

This preserves the "pretty" url in the browser address bar. I have also updated all my links on the site to use the extensionless URLs.

The problem is that the underlying `.aspx` pages can still be accessed directly and I'd like to prevent this.

If a user browses to `http://www.mytest.com/contact.aspx` I'd like it to either redirect/rewrite to `http://www.mytest.com/contact`, or at the very least just return a "Page not found".

**Update:**

I managed to get this working by redirecting all `.aspx` pages to the home directory. This isn't ideal as I'd prefer to send them to the non-`.aspx` version, but it will do for now.

```
<rule name="Block .aspx" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url=".aspx" />  
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" />  
</rule>`
```

How do I rewrite and redirect URLs that directly address `.aspx` pages to my friendly URL format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rule will strip the `.aspx` from the URL and then redirect the browser to the extensionless URL:

```
<rule name="Redirect to friendly" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)\.aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

A problem I would foresee with this approach (and with your other rule) is if you have a page called `contact.aspx` and a folder named `/contact`. This could produce some unexpected problems.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for,I thought I'd tried that but maybe I got the syntax slightly wrong.